# Do relational metaphysics and analytic philosophy conflict via relational vs external properties?

Tags: metaphysics, analytic-philosophy, relations

You might first think, relations do indeed involve external properties of the relata. But I want to be careful. Are relational properties, a la relational quantum mechanics say, and external properties, a la analytic philosophy, conflicting in that there can't only be relational properties if there are external properties? If this is indeed an issue, then I do see a conflict via ["Quantum mechanics is a theory about the physical description of physical systems relative to other systems, and this is a complete description of the world"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics). I.e. if relational properties are complete and that rules out external properties by there being only relational ones, then there is a conflict.

And for a source that analytic philosophy requires external properties, here's [Cahoone](https://youtu.be/00EzD8yWhmw?list=PLvu4hd_80Ly9a_E0SMn7M6mvSt0v8eqpG&t=93) "[analysts] insisted on the reality of external relations".

The main reason I think relational metaphysics and analytic philosophy conflict is that if there are only relational properties, that might rule out external properties. But I'm not sure how the two types of properties can coexist.

Comment: The "internal/external" property terminology is rarely used these days, it goes back to Aristotelian attempts to reduce polyadic relations to monadic ones, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/#Rela). Do you, perhaps, mean [extrinsic properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intrinsic-extrinsic/#RelaVsNonRelaProp)? But the extrinsic/intrinsic distinction is muddy and, in any case, extrinsicality is relative, a relation is extrinsic to its relata but intrinsic to their joint system. So even purely relational ontologies can very well have both.

Comment: @Conifold I cant quite shake the feeling that analysis has some kind of external/extrinsic vantage it strongly desires that conflicts with relational ontologies. Or if relational QM takes off it will leave behind analysis as a method. Maybe I latched onto the wrong pillar of analysis to spell this out more (Cahoone gives 3), or maybe that feeling is ultimately wrong. I think your comment settles that this pillar is not in conflict at least

Comment: One issue I can see is that maybe a "complete description" has to be, at its core, intrinsic, while relational ontologies can be seen as inherently *non*-intrinsic. But you were asking about a conflict with external/extrinsic instead, so I am not sure if this is related. Relational ontologies and structuralisms traditionally have difficulties explaining what free floating relations or structures are supposed to be "in themselves" if all "substances" or "objects" are reduced to mere placeholders in them. A Kantian response would be - we can never know and we do not need to know.

Comment: @Conifold Is the intrinsic conflict because complete implies holism implies intrinsic? I guess I don't think complete -> holism, but not sure if that's even your line of thinking. I was looking at the indispensible, external relation of math to science (a product of analytic philosophy's success?) and given that math is objective, it made me confused about a relational scientific theory on top of this.